# I can't change SATA hard disk (working in UDMA) to PIO mode in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bad-sectors, bad-blocks, dma

I'm trying to disable DMA in my SATA 3.5" hard disk drive to work in PIO mode because for recovering some bad sectors from a failing disk with GNU ddrescue

I am using PartedMagic Linux live CD and I tried to modify it with hdparm. The disk is using UDMA6 so I run:

```
hdparm -p4 /dev/sda
```

It showed me the following error (and I tried with several modes, not only PIO4):

```
Attempting to set PIO mode to 0
HDIO_SET_PIO_MODE failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Also, I tried other Linux live systems like SystemRescueCD adding the kernel parameter **libata.dma=0** at boot time. Same results and it still shows me that is using with UDMA6...

I read about libata.force but I don't understand the command very well. I tried the following parameters at boot time of SystemRescueCD and the system didn't recognized the HDD this time LOL (so i restarted again after that I leave this command aside).

```
libata.dma=0 libata.force=
```

I look at the BIOS options and I didn't found  any DMA option or similar...

Any suggestions?

Off the record:

It's an old desktop computer (13 years old x64 AMD) and I don't have any other computer to do the recovery (my other computer is a laptop and I can't conect the disk directly to the motherboard without doing a mess...)

Comment: 1. You [usually?] do not disable that on a disk. You change it at the controller which will then talk ancient PIO mode to the disk.  If you old desktop only speaks classic IDE then this will be used automatically but both controller(desktop) and disk. 

2. Why do you want to do that? I read the sentence which said 'for recovering some bad sectors' but why not do that in normal AHCI mode?

Comment: What indication do you have that you need PIO mode?  As far as I know ddrescue **should** work in either.

Comment: Yes, ddrescue works perfectly in DMA mode. Actually I did many successful images on multiples HDD by using it. The thing is, In hard drive image forensics there are some cases that you have deal with failing disks in quite diferent approaches in other to get better chance to improve your badblocks reading chances.

Comment: This is one of those cases... I have recovered 86% of the disk but I am stuck in an area where every time I found a badblock the disk disconnect with an I/O error and ddrescue mark all sectors as non scrapped. I run different options (forwards, backwards, no cache, jumping blocks...) and I can confirm it: every time i found a badblock my HDD disconnects. I know that many foresincs experts change to PIO mode because you get better reads in some cases where your HDD fails (I/O errors for instance). I never tried to set PIO because I never had problems creating the image but every disk is a world

Comment: Also, thank you both for your time.  @Hennes It is old but not that old hehe. The motherboard is really nice and is it came with six SATA connectors. In the BIOS It shows me Primary master IDE, Secondary IDE, and the 6 SATA Options. The HDD is recognized as the SATA5 disk. In the SATA5 menu entry I can see "Extended IDE" option (auto) and if i disable it the disk is still listed in the general menu of the BIOS but its attributes dissapear inside that menu (size, cylinders...). Inside primary and secondary IDE entries I dissabled the UDMA option (It doesn't appear in the SATAs entries).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would PIO mode get better reads? If the embedded controller of the HD fails to read the block, it really doesn't matter what method it uses to transfer data to the host. PIO mode would help if the EC is damaged, and if bad transfers via DMA happen, but this is a very rare failure mode .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how PIO/DMA mode affects how a drive will read bad sectors.

But try this.

- Disable AHCI in BIOS.
- What's the kernel version on your live CD?  Try using something as recent as possible, like a Debian live CD (should have `ddrescue` and `hdparm` on it - if not, you can `apt-get install` them.)  Some `hdparm` features may be quirky if the Linux kernel is too old.
- Boot system with case open and drive power cable unattached.  Wait until live CD boots, then carefully attach power cable.  This is safe for SATA drives if you do not touch the drive circuit board (handle by edges only and set on a non-static elevated surface such as top of computer) and are static-electricity free (touch metal part of case before handling drive).  This will bypass any ATA security commands the BIOS might be sending on boot and interfering.  Try doing what the accepted answer for [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/5336/how-do-i-make-linux-recognize-a-new-sata-dev-sda-drive-i-hot-swapped-in-without) says if the drive is not visible after connecting.

EDIT: According to [this](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Enabling_DMA_Mode_Transfers) SATA drives may not support PIO mode (PIO was an EIDE thing before SATA came to pass).  However I think if you disable AHCI in BIOS, the controller is essentially emulating EIDE, so it may still work.

Comment: As I said in the comments above, I your disks presents some reading or I/O errors you can get better chances by disabling DMA in the controller at the same way you can deal with USB HDD errors better if you connect your external disk directly to your SATA conector of your motherboard. Is slower but it can bring some light... I never need to do some alternative methods like this... until now. By the way, I have no option to disable AHCI in bios, I can only choose ACHI in the JMicron Raid controller option (which is auto) but I supposse it is Raid related and I don't use RAID in this computer.

Comment: You might need to tell ddrescue to start after the sector (writing to another file then recombining them later) that makes the drive produce an error.  If all sectors after that one causes the drive to report an error, you have something weird going on ...

Comment: There's a big difference between connecting USB HDD's directly to SATA (this removes the SATA-to-USB bridge, which can get in the way, especially if it's a cheap Chinese one with bugs in the firmware), and switching from DMA to PIO mode (which only helps of the EC of the HDD is damaged).

Comment: I rebooted the system so my disk is recognized correctly again and I attack the problem in different direction jumpling that first bad block and marking the end of the domain as non tried (because I thought it was weird, and probly that final block wasn't a bad block. I was right. I recovered all the surrounding areas but that first bad block it causes the disc to disconnect. All went nicely but then I found other bad block and did the same (marked as non scrapped the rest of the domain and as badblock the final block of the domain). I know that probably is only that first block the badblock

Comment: But what happens is that every time a badblock the HDD is not recognized (I/O error) and ddrescue stops in its own way by marking the rest as non scrapped... and obviously i need to restart again the computer.... by the way, I started this image recovery thing because smart told me I have 1 reallocated sector and the disk is gonna fail some day... I could try again to keep doing the image recovery in that 3 gb  left i wanted to try the PIO thing and other approaches for the learning thing. Anyway, probably my partition table is instact in the image and I have almost the image perfect....

Comment: @LawrenceC That's right the analogy wasn't the best. But I've read and heard many forensic experts saying that you can improve the reading chances in badblocks with PIO mode or even a different interface like UDMA3 instead UDMA6 you can improve the situation.

Comment: @LawrenceC Regarding your updated answer, that's was one of the things thought that SATA doesn't supported PIO. I read about PIO in forensics but I never read nothing specifying if it was a SATA or IDE disk scenario... that explains why  the disk keep using UDMA...  I am gonna look the BIOS settings again I search for the AHCI option.